# Why is there shimmery white dust coming from my floor vents?

Tags: hvac, furnace, ducts, central-heating

There is a white dust settling around all of my downstairs floor vents. It’s got a shimmer to it. I haven’t noticed it upstairs coming from the ceiling vents.

We had all new HVAC done a year ago when we bought the house, unfortunately I really don’t know the system details.

Is this something to be concerned about?[image]

Comment: Can you provide a close up picture?

Comment: Also, what year was the house built and do you have children? I swear this is relevant

Comment: I’ll take a photo when I get home. The house was built in 1919 and yes I have two kids.

Comment: UnhandledExcepSean I added a photo. Hard to get a good shot, and I dusted earlier today so got rid of most of it. It’s like an ashy texture, some of the “chunks” are bigger than others but it all turns to shimmery dust if you touch it.

Comment: The only way to know what it is , is to have it tested. Was new duct work added? In a house of this age I would bet a stud bay is being used for the supply and return, probably plaster in that case. When the air stops anything suspended will fall to the lower level.

Comment: All of the ducts are new.